# Re attach Socket

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

So I have a socket server running, inside an asp.net ( C# ) application (very bad approach) that notifies any device connected,
It was like that when I started working at this company and changing it is not on a priority to my supervisors even though it will be better.

So what happens is when we do an update to the Website the Socket connection stays open (in another thread), then we have to restart the Server, but what I want to do is somehow get the Thread ID on startup of the Socket, then store it, if the update is done it should reattach to that thread and end the Socket somehow or reset it.

Is this possible?

this is sample code

```
    private void Start()
    {
        _socketServer = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotificationSocketPort"]));
        _socketServer.Start();
        _acceptingThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var client = _socketServer.AcceptTcpClient();
                    StartClient(client);
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
                {
                    _acceptingThread = null;
                    _socketServer = null;
                    Start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        _acceptingThread.Start();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if (_acceptingThread != null)
        {

            _acceptingThread.Abort(0x0);
            _socketServer.Stop();
            _acceptingThread = null;
            _socketServer = null;
        }
    }
```

In global.asax

```
protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SocketNotifier.GetNotifierInstance().Close();
}
```

The SocketNotifier is using the Singleton Design Pattern

Comment: When you update the website, you'd usually cause a recyclation of the application (or even the whole pool), which kills all the threads. The only way to update a part of the website is if it's not precompiled, and that's likely a bad idea anyway. I'd guess the problem isn't that the socket stays open, just that it doesn't shutdown properly so it might linger in half-open state. Perhaps you'd like to update with more info about the specific implementation or sample code that shows the behaviour you're describing?

Comment: I updated and added from Startup to Shutting Down, this is how it was when I started working at the Company

Comment: You want all connections to stay open although the IIS worker process terminates and a new one is started. Correct?

Comment: Are you sure the Socket and its thread is surviving the update? I don't think that should happen at all. You'd have to recreate the socket on application start or something to get it working again, but it should be dead while the process is restarting.

Comment: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
This is the Exception we are recieving

@usr no they stay open that is the problem after IIS worker process terminates and a new one is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They [the sockets] stay open that is the problem after IIS worker process terminates and a new one is started

Probably, IIS has trouble shutting down the old process. That keeps the socket open. Your socket thread is a foreground thread. It does not prevent process termination. Also, aborting a thread does not affect IO. And your socket listening method automatically restarts itself when the socket is closed.

Remove these problems. Make the thread a background thread. Don't abort it. Don't restart it in case of an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: This seemed to have worked,I updated the server then I restarted my server (physical), updated again and the exception seemed to be gone and the external devices can nou connect normally

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0(v=vs.110).aspx

This also helped me understand the difference

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, this is just the wrong approach. Web apps restart, and should be expected to restart. Sockets don't like that, and should not be expected to like that. Your best bet here would be to re-write the socket code as a windows service - that way it can keep running independently of the web-app.

Comment: That was my suggestion to my supervisor, I do have socket experience to do this but my supervisor turned my suggestions down about 6 times. So that is a no go at the moment, even though I know this is the better approach, and im the unlucky bastart to solve his code without creating a new project :(

Comment: @DonaldJansen it isn't about being a "better" approach; it is about the suggested approach (in the question) simply not being viable in the first place.